# Do any members of Congress support a British-style socialized healthcare system?

Tags: united-states, congress, healthcare, socialism

A number of Democratic members of Congress, Senator Bernie Sanders being the most prominent, support a Canadian-style single-payer system where doctors and hospitals are private, but health insurance is run by the government.  But my question is, are there any members of Congress who support a British-style socialized healthcare system, where not just health insurance but healthcare providers like doctors and hospitals are part of the government?

Does Congresswoman Alexandria Ocasio-Cortez support such a system, for instance?

Comment: The question is a little odd as almost all European countries have free universal healthcare and none of have the British system. Are you really interested in the idiosyncratic British health care system or is your real interest in free universal healthcare?

Comment: I mentioned this in a comment below, but you have some misconceptions about the British system: primary care under the NHS is delivered by private practices (along with pharmacy and dentistry). Additionally, unlike Canada, the British have a parallel private insurance, primary care, and hospital system which covers ~10% of the population, who opt-out of NHS. Also, unlike Canada, doctors can work in both private and public systems.

Comment: Whoever possibly supports it has no chance of succeeding. The medical-industrial complex is probably more powerful than the military-industrial one; health costs exceed military spending six-fold. Putting 18% of the GDP under government control would indeed amount to a socialist revolution.

Comment: @user71659 UK NHS GP practices are privately run, but they all operate under an NHS contract.  They are *heavily* tied to the NHS - they cannot provide additional private medical care for instance.  The NHS tells them when to jump and how high, and the only recourse for the GP practice is to withdraw from their NHS contract, which is a complicated and messy process.  The fact that NHS GP practices are privately owned is an idiosyncracy that dates back to when the NHS was first created - GPs didnt want to be owned by the NHS.

Comment: @user71659 fully private GPs (ones without an NHS contract) also cannot provide a full service - in many cases they have to write a letter of referral back to the patients NHS GP requesting that they refer them on to a specialist for example.  Private hospitals in general also do not provide the full level of service an NHS hospital will - for example, while Spire hospitals do provide surgery as a service, they do not provide an emergency response if anything goes wrong during that surgery.  They will call an ambulance and you will be taken to the nearest NHS ER.

Comment: @Moo The concept of NHS contract is similar to HMO and Medicare restrictions in the US. Just like the US, there's ways around it, e.g. by having a doctor work for two legal entities, which can even be in the same building. NHS allows public specialists to work privately after 40 hours a week. A private GP would not refer to a NHS specialist, they would refer to a private specialist. This situation is very different from Canada where private insurance that overlaps public coverage is simply banned: doctors are under public insurance or they are 100% cash.

Comment: @user71659 my wifes an NHS GP - she cant legally work for anyone else when holding an NHS GP practice service provision contract.  Those contracts also limit what contracted GPs to the practice can do in a similar vein.  The only GP which can flit between NHS and private is a locum.  The NHS does indeed allow public specialists to work privately, but the NHS relationship with GPs is entirely different to that of a doctor in a hospital contract - junior doctors under a hospital contract are also required to first offer any hours over 40 to their NHS employer first.

Comment: @user71659 there is also a limit to what private specialists can do - they cant prescribe the full range of drugs available under NICE, for example, only an NHS doctor can.  So you end up going to a private GP or a private specialist for diagnosis, and back to the NHS for treatment a lot of the time.

Comment: @user71659 also, an NHS GP generally wont have the time to do private work - my wife regularly started work at 7.30am and finished at 8pm, to provide a regular surgery hours of 8am-6pm.  She worked 4 days a week doing that, and still got burnt out (we left the UK, we are now in New Zealand where there is a public/private healthcare system but I would still have the NHS over it - the NHS may destroy its staff, but its still the best in the world).  And the government wanted her to work late and at weekends, with no extra staff.

Comment: @Moo Returning to the point, the UK is not what the OP thinks. There is non-trivial private insurance, private hospitals, and private practice. I think the OP is thinking of a model like Kaiser Permanente in the US: Kaiser is the insurance company while simultaneously owning and employing 100% of primary care, hospital, ER, specialists, and pharmacy.

Comment: @user71659 I personally think you are overstating the impact of private healthcare in the UK - its there, certainly, but the average person in the street doesn't have private healthcare insurance, and most employers in the UK don't offer it as a benefit.

Comment: @Moo I think you're missing that there's systems with far higher levels of integration and single-party ownership, even in the US, than NHS. Even my US employer's plan is like that: they are affiliated with a hospital group, so we go to their primary care, specialist, hospital, emergency room, and pharmacy, or else its out-of-pocket. The quality of care is mediocre, but they are very efficient.

Comment: @user71659 People don't "opt out" of the NHS, it's funded by general taxation. They purchase *additional* healthcare privately

Answer (score 19):

## What the Government Provides Today

In the US as of January 2019, the government provides healthcare both directly and indirectly. Its direct programs (i.e. state ownership and employment of facilities and providers) are exclusively for [members of the military](https://health.mil/), [veterans](https://www.va.gov/health/) or [Native Americans](https://www.ihs.gov/), and are managed by the Department of Defense (through the services themselves), the Department of Veterans Affairs or the Department of Health and Human Services. Indirect care (i.e. health insurance) is provided through Medicare for the elderly; Medicaid for the poor (administered by the several states); Tricare for active duty or retired military; and a patchwork of other programs (e.g. CHIP, SCHIP).

## Party Platforms & Politicians

As a party, [the Democrats tend to favor either the existing ACA system](https://democrats.org/about/party-platform/#universal-health) or [a "single-payer"/"Medicare-for-All" plan](https://outline.com/nXCbHG) (which is typically loosely defined). [The Republicans, for their part, tend to advocate for a more market-centered plan that relies on federalism and streamlining legal issues](https://gop.com/platform/renewing-american-values/#Item10). Given the failure of the GOP in the last Congress to coalesce around any particular system, we can only say for sure that they oppose the ACA and single-payer.

Given that there are 435 members of the House and 100 senators, I would guess at least one advocates for or has advocated for a VA-for-all type of system. However, several web searches have turned up nothing. "Medicare-for-All" is a much more common phrase.

### Ocasio-Cortez

Since the question asked about Ocasio-Cortez, during a [recent interview with Jake Tapper on CNN](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6CWUgPWRhxU&feature=youtu.be&t=34), she stated:

> Well, one of the things we need to realize when we look at something like Medicare-for-All, Medicare-for-all would save the American People a very large amount of money, and what we see as well is that these systems are not just pie-in-the-sky. Many of them are accomplished by every modern civilized democracy in the Western world. **The United Kingdom has a form of single-payer health care**, Canada, France, Germany. *[Emphasis added]*

#### What does she mean?

The UK, Canada, France and Germany each have quite different models for how they provide health care to their populations. The UK itself has a heavily-nationalized system (albeit with certain private providers) and Canada has a single universal insurance plan (i.e. true single-payer). Furthermore, France and Germany are both "universal multi-payer," with the state paying a large percentage of medical bills and citizens or supplemental insurance being responsible for the remainder. Given that, a fair interpretation is that Ocasio-Cortez is using "single-payer" as a shorthand for all "universal" systems, with the exception of the current universal American system under the ACA.

## Summary

Without a concrete proposal, we can only speculate on what "single-payer" or "Medicare-for-All" actually mean, but a fair guess is something on the spectrum between France/Germany and Canada. While the UK is sometimes mentioned as having a "single-payer" system, it usually is mentioned alongside Canada and other Western countries, which have diverse health care systems. Few or no politicians are advocating "VA-for-All," which would be the closest American analogue to Britain's National Health Service, so we can fairly assume that direct nationalization only has marginal support in the US.

Comment: "we can fairly assume that direct nationalization only has marginal support in the US" - agreed, and with good reason.  The US's direct care services -- by which I mainly mean the VA -- have been notoriously problematic, with recent scandals primarily involving excessive waits for care and falsification of records, at multiple VA hospitals.  There are some things that the VA reputedly does well, but although Medicare-for-All may have some traction, nothing that smells like VA-for-All is likely to be well received any time soon.

Comment: It's incorrect to say the UK has "outright nationalization", it's rather complex. First, public primary care practices (GP) are independent private entities, like in the US (excluding Kaiser), under contract to the NHS. Second, about 10% of the UK has opted-out of the NHS system and purchases private insurance. There exists private hospitals and private primary care. NHS does contract some services to this private sector and vice versa. A doctor can work in both sectors, charging different rates, unlike Canada's "all or nothing" policy.

Comment: @user71659 I've updated to characterize more accurately the UK's system as "heavily nationalized" with some clarification. Still, 90% of Britons use the National Health Service. It's clearly **much** more nationalized (in terms of government ownership) than either Canada or America.

Comment: @Andrew The UK general practice system involves essentially no govt ownership. It is however "free at the point of delivery" and taxpayer funded.

Comment: Correction: In Germany the state *doesn't* pay a large percentage of medical bills etc; the systems is mostly financed by the insured (and their employers).

Comment: @user71659 You do not opt out of the UK NS you can pay to have some things done ut not opt out. e/g/ my parents used NHS for most things but for somethings .g. removal of wisdom teeth used a private hospital.

Comment: @MartinSchröder But in Germany, the fees of those "insurances" are more related to your income than the risk. So really it's a tax and those "insurers" are closet government agencies. They are called differently, but what things are called can't be the basis for comparing different systems.

Comment: @John The insurers go to great lengths to be *not* directly controlled by the government. You confuse tax and insurance.

Comment: @MartinSchröder No, you do, like nearly all Germans. Many branches of government are independent of the executive and legislative, like the judiciary or central banks. That doesn't stop these institutions from being government. Same with public health insurers. That those latter ones aren't called government is tradition, nothing else.